# Using Weka for Text Classification

Tags: java, classification, weka

I'm new to Weka!

My purpose is to classify an existing article to 2 categories: EDUCATION or ENTERTAINMENT.

I already have 400 articles in EDUCATION category and 400 articles in ENTERTAINMENT.

So how to create arff input file for Weka? Or any other solutions with Weka?

(Sorry for my bad English and thank you)

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Converting+CSV+to+ARFF) shows how to convert CSV format to ARFF, provided that your data set is in CSV format.

However, if you do not have a data set yet, you need to perform a lot of tasks beforehand.

Comment: Excuse me, my file is text file, not in CSV format. I wondered how to represent these text files in csv or arff formats! Ah, I use n-grams to create Feature vector...

Answer (score 0):

Although it may seem like a long journey, you can actually do it. Everything you try to do is related to the subject of Text Mining. I think you can learn a lot from [this link](https://www.tidytextmining.com/tidytext.html). In addition, the information I think may be useful to you is:

1. First of all, open your file in each text form and paste it into one line in a spreadsheet program (such as Excel). In the column next to it, type the document type (Education or Entertaintment). You will have a total of 800 lines.
2. Click "Save As" in the File menu in Excel and select the file type as ".csv". And save it as ".csv". (After clicking "Save" in "Excel", he asks if you want to save the workbook as such "Excel". I think "No".
3. To open your ".csv" file in "Weka": Select "Open File" in "Weka", mark .csv as the file type and select your ".csv" file.
4. Select "StringToVector" from the "Filter -> Choose" list. You can check [this address](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.stable/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/StringToWordVector.html) for the necessary parameter settings.
5. You will get the desired file in ".arff" format with the "Save" command in Weka.

[image: StringToVector_in_Weka]

I hope it helps. Good luck.